# Will sqoop delete all the existing data files?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, rdbms

I imported data from RDBMS to HDFS through **sqoop** with the following command:
`sqoop import --connect ... --table ...  --hive-import  --hive-table --m 20`  etc.
So this command will create 20 files under a dir in hdfs.

If I decide later to import another data and overwrite the existing one I will use the following command: `sqoop import --connect ... --table ...  --hive-import  --hive-overwrite --hive-table --m 10`.

*What will be the behaviour of the **sqoop** ?*

1. Sqoop will go to the dir and **remove all the previous 20** files and **create 
   10 new ones.**
2. Sqool will remove all the data from 20 files and then write the new data at 10 
   random files from the exsiting 20.

Answer (score 0):

**`Option 1`**

Sqoop will just **`overwrite the existing 20 files with new 10 files`**.

For more info refer to [this](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive) and [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/193934/sqoop-import-mssql-table-into-hdfs.html) links.